# flash record and playback movieclips

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

My goal is to make a replay function: I have to "record" 3 moviesclips movements for N seconds and play them back.

Is there a library avaible to do it or a simple way ? Or do I need it from scratch ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be enough creating an array with the properties of each movieclip, for each frame add this to the array:

```
recordArray.push ( mc.transform.matrix.clone() );
```

then when you're done recording, to play the thing back, simply do:

```
mc.transform.matrix = recordArray[index];
```

if you're doing other things than adjusting the position / scale / rotation of the mc, you will need to store that information as well!